# Access Child theme template page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a page located in **wp-content/themes/twentyninetneen-child/my_custom_page.php**.

I simply want to type in: http://mywebsite.com/my_custom_page  in order to access that page.

Is this possible?

Comment: Look up the documentation on custom WordPress page templates, that should get you on the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution with Wordpress 5.2.2.

I first created a page.  I made the title of the page "mypage".

- This creates a `post` record of `post_type` = page
- The `post_name` = 'mypage' (which is important for the customized page template file name below).

Within my child theme directory, I then created a template named "page-mypage.php".  Due to the wordpress template hierarchy: when this page loads: it will look for a template file with this exact name.

Answer (score 1):

1. Give a name to that page as Template Name
2. Create Add New page and select that template from the right sidebar.

[Example Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B83CP.png)

Comment: Thanks.  That would certainly work in classic editor, but unfortunately doesn't seem to work in wordpress 5+.

Comment: @Neil -- Create this template file on the root of your child theme. for more info: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use